# Error Could not initialize class in running react-native android

Tags: react-native

when i want to run-android with react native after initializing the app this error occurrs :

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\React\FirstApp\android\app\build.gradle' line: 1
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

  > Could not initialize class com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\React\FirstApp\android\app\build.gradle' line: 1
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

  > Could not initialize class com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s

```
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:629:11)
at execFileSync (child_process.js:647:13)
at runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\React\FirstApp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:75:39)
at buildAndRun (C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\React\FirstApp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:137:41)
at then.result (C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\React\FirstApp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:103:12)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```